# Is this black locust?

Tags: identification, trees

This grows in Modiin, Israel. The leaves look like black locust (pseudoacacia robinia) to me, but the branches are very knobby. Can anyone identify it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know what it is, but I'm reasonably confident that it is NOT Black Locust. The leaves are too thick and of a different shape from Black Locust. Also the bark is different as is the growth habit (though this could be the result of odd pruning/cutting.

Comment: Not a Russian olive. Maybe a Eucalypt of some sort? Those *are* compound leaves though, aren't they?

Comment: A close picture of the main trunk would be helpful. Black locust has interesting bark. Does it have thorns?

Comment: Could it be an Acacia?

Comment: No, it doesn't have thorns.

Comment: Do you remember the flowers? Do you find some fruits?

Comment: There are neither around the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure, there are something familiar, but also something different.

If I should bet on something, I would bet on *Ceratonia siliqua*, looking on internet, sometime the leaves are similar to the plants in your photo.

For reference: I found such nice list: http://www.flowersinisrael.com/plant_list_TreesinIsrael.htm

Comment: It's not a carob tree.